# handling synchronous and asynchronous function on button click

Tags: javascript, ajax, button

I have a button in my html page, on clicking that button, I want to do 2 things -- start a progress bar and second, run a ajax call to a REST API in the background to fetch the data. If i have one method which does both these things, it doesn't return till REST API returns ( I am using promise), so, the purpose of the progress bar is lost. How do I call both these functions simultaneously on click of a button?

Code:

````
```javascript``` 

    function showProgress(){
    var x = document.getElementById("progressCircle");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
                    x.style.display = "block";
    }
  }


function loadData(){
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
   var req = {
                    url: urlWithData,
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "text/xml",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (data) {
                        resolve(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        loginfo("Failed to get the data from database" +
                                "textStatus: " + textStatus +
                                "errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                    },
                    description: "Getting required data"
                };
                $.ajax(req);
                });
       return promise;
}

function getData(){
    showProgress();
    loadData().then(function(data){
       // loading data in html way
    }
}


```html```  

<oj-button id='retrieveData' disabled='false' on-oj-action='[[getData]]'>

<div class="oj-hybrid-padding">
    <div class="oj-panel oj-panel-alt7 oj-margin" >
        <h4 id="result"  data-bind="text:label_result_text"></h4>
        <oj-progress id="progressCircle" type="circle" value="-1" style='display:none'></oj-progress>
        <br/>
        <pre id="dataReturned" style="pointer-events:none;"><oj-bind-text value="[[message]]"></oj-bind-text></pre>
    </div>
</div>
````

Comment: are you showing progress `1% to 100%` ?. or just loading?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to help you with code we can't see. Please add a [mcve] of the click handler to the question.

Comment: showing progress as just loading.

Answer (score 1):

> If i have one method which does both these things, it doesn't return till REST API returns ( I am using promise)

Yes, it does. The promise may not have settled yet, but the function returns. If it's an `async` function, it returns a promise. (It also returns a promise if you've returned the result of calling `.then` or `.catch` on the promise from the REST API call.)

You haven't shown us your code, but what you want will look something like this:

```
function handler(evt) {
    //           ^^^−−−−−− If you need it for anything

    showProgressIndicator();
    startRestAPICall()
    .then(result => {
        // Use the result
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle/display the error
    })
    .finally(() => {
        hideProgressIndicator();
    });
}
```

Live Example (using `setTimeout` to emulate the REST API call):

```js
function showProgressIndicator() {
    document.getElementById("loading").classList.remove("hidden");
}
function hideProgressIndicator() {
    document.getElementById("loading").classList.add("hidden");
}

function startRestAPICall() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1500, "this is the data");
    });
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", handler);

function handler(evt) {
    //           ^^^−−−−−− If you need it for anything
    this.disabled = true; // Disable the button

    showProgressIndicator();
    startRestAPICall()
    .then(result => {
        // Use the result
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent = result;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle/display the error
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.className = "error";
        p.textContent = String(error);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        hideProgressIndicator();
        this.disabled = false; // Re-enable the button
    });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me">
<div id="loading" class="hidden"><em>Loading...</em></div>
```

Comment: I tried this, and it still doesn't work for me. I tried increasing the timeout of the startRestAPICall to 1 minute, and I notice that the progress indicator doesn't show up till a minute is complete. Basically, the method doesn't return till startRestAPICall finishes. Can you help?

Comment: Thank you for the code, by the way. This is exactly similar to the code I have.

Comment: @coder - As I said, it's nearly impossible to help you with code we can't see. From your description, it sounds like your REST API call is synchronous (which is a Bad Thing™), but...

Comment: ok, I have updated the problem with the sample code..

Comment: @coder - Remove the `async: false` from `req`. That makes the call synchronous, which is a Bad Thing™. It completely blocks the UI of the browser, including preventing it from updating the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing loading bar then this will work :

```
const buttonClick = () => {
showLoading() // function handling showing the bar on button click
 $.ajax({ // jquery ajax just for representing ajax call, replace with your ajax call

        'url' : 'http://myapi/api',
        'type' : 'GET',
        'data' : {
            myData
        },
        'success' : function(data) {              
          hideLoading() // function handling hiding the bar on success
        },
        'error' : function(request,error)
        {
            alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged or mentioned in the question.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, coz I want to show the "Loading" message only when the user clicks on the button, and want to hide the "Loading" message once the API returns. Basically, need 2 actions to be triggered when button is clicked. One is synchronous, another asynchronous.

Comment: I mean to say, you could handle your showing loading bar on `loading = true` and hide on `loading=false`. simply say replace `loading=true` with `showLoading()` function and `loading=false` with `hideLoading()`. let me update answer.